# Chaining logging with a simple expression in Scala

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j

I usually use Scala with SLF4J through the Loggable wrapper in LiftWeb. This works decently well with the exception of the quite common method made up only from *1 chain of expressions*.

So if you want to add logging to such a method, the simply beautiful, no curly brackets

```
def method1():Z = a.doX(x).doY(y).doZ()
```

must become:

```
def method1():Z = {
  val v = a.doX(x).doY(y).doZ()
  logger.info("the value is %s".format(v))
  v
}
```

Not quite the same, is it? I gave it a try to solve it with this:

```
class ChainableLoggable[T](val v:T){
  def logInfo(logger:Logger, msg:String, other:Any*):T = {
    logger.info(msg.format(v, other))
    v
  }
}
implicit def anyToChainableLogger[T](v:T):ChainableLoggable[T] = new ChainableLoggable(v)
```

Now I can use a simpler form

```
 def method1():Z = a.doX(x).doY(y).doZ() logInfo(logger, "the value is %s")
```

However 1 extra object instantiation and an implicit from Any starts to look like a code stink.

Does anyone know of any better solution? Or maybe I shouldn't even bother with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2.10 has just a solution for you - that's a new feature [Value Class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) which allows you to gain the same effect as the implicit wrappers provide but with no overhead coming from instantiation of those wrapper classes. To apply it you'll have to rewrite your code like so:

```
implicit class ChainableLoggable[T](val v : T) extends AnyVal {
  def logInfo(logger:Logger, msg:String, other:Any*) : T = {
    logger.info(msg.format(v, other))
    v
  }
}
```

Under the hood the compiler will transform the `logInfo` into an analogue of Java's common "util" static method by prepending your `v : T` to it's argument list and updating its usages accordingly - see, nothing gets instantiated.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the JVM _already_ can, in some cases, elide most or all of the overhead on these sorts of implicits, but that the value class approach removes a lot of the burden from the JVM, making equivalent or near-equivalent performance likely.  Thus, with a value class the stance should be, "Assume it's fast unless a test shows otherwise," while without it should be "Assume it's slow (but only as slow as creating an extra wrapper object or two) unless a test shows otherwise."

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the right way to do it, especially if you don't have the tap implicit around (not in the standard library, but something like this is fairly widely used--and `tap` is standard in Ruby):

```
class TapAnything[A](a: A) {
  def tap(f: A => Any): A = { f(a); a }
}
implicit def anything_can_be_tapped[A](a: A) = new TapAnything(a)
```

With this, it's less essential to have the info implicit on its own, but if you use it it's an improvement over

```
.tap(v => logger.info("the value is %s".format(v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using implicits, you can define functions like this one in your own logging trait. Maybe not as pretty as the solution with implicits though.

```
def info[A](a:A)(message:A=>String) = {
  logger.info(message(a))
  a
}

info(a.doX(x).doY(y).doZ())("the value is " + _)
```